# Custom reset password template after forgot password request

Tags: templates, login, password

I've made a custom login template where you can login or request a link that sends you to the reset password form. What I need to do is make that unique link redirect to a custom reset password template (not wordpress's default). So this is kind of a two part question on how first to send a link to a custom template and how to show a custom reset password template (not the "forgot password form). Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this article suite completely - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/wordpress-custom-forgot-password-page/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin does this. You may want to dig into the source and figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope my answer will help someone, I was searching for an answer for a couple of hours.
So I found the template in woocommerce/myaccount/form-reset-password.php
Copy that file to your custom theme (remember to keep the same file location (with all the folders)), and make changes inside it, but keep all "do_action" functions.